# extract specific json values from url and put as array

Tags: php, json, sparklines

I want to extract specific values from Alpha Vantage API and want to display in a Sparkline chart.

I have a JSON file like -

```
    {
        "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Intraday Prices and Volumes for Digital Currency",
            "2. Digital Currency Code": "BTC",
            "3. Digital Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
            "4. Market Code": "EUR",
            "5. Market Name": "Euro",
            "6. Interval": "5min",
            "7. Last Refreshed": "2018-05-05 09:30:00",
            "8. Time Zone": "UTC"
        },
        "Time Series (Digital Currency Intraday)": {
            "2018-05-05 09:30:00": {
                "1a. price (EUR)": "8213.91934125",
                "1b. price (USD)": "9833.29603162",
                "2. volume": "14118.15104183",
                "3. market cap (USD)": "138827958.61346000"
            },
            "2018-05-05 09:25:00": {
                "1a. price (EUR)": "8205.43730260",
                "1b. price (USD)": "9823.14175648",
                "2. volume": "14138.79003689",
                "3. market cap (USD)": "138887338.79747999"
            }
           .
           .
           .
        }
   }
```

I want to extract only `"1b. price (USD)": "9833.29603162"` this values and put them is a JS array

```
var myvalues = [9833.296,9823.141,...];
```

I am using to do some other tasks. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you convert json to array/object for start?

Comment: short answer: `json_decode($json, true)` plus iterating over the time series field "array" and retrieving every 1b. price

Comment: @Glavić I have converted to PHP array. I have very little idea about JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract specific data using JSON you can use the code below. For each library you need to change the function. The names of the library and what Function name you need to use is in the alpah vantage documentation.

https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#

```
    ### FUNADMENTAL DATA > COMPANY OVERVIEW ###
    # https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

base_url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'
params = {'function': 'OVERVIEW',
         'symbol': stock_ticker,
         'apikey': keys}
response_data_overview = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

data_overview_Name = response_data_overview.json()['Name']
data_overview_AssetType = response_data_overview.json()['AssetType']
data_overview_Description = response_data_overview.json()['Description']
data_overview_Exchange = response_data_overview.json()['Exchange']
data_overview_Currency = response_data_overview.json()['Currency']
data_overview_Country = response_data_overview.json()['Country']
data_overview_Sector = response_data_overview.json()['Sector']
data_overview_Industry = response_data_overview.json()['Industry']
data_overview_Address = response_data_overview.json()['Address']
```